# Squid 3.3.8 HTTPS (not transparent)

Tags: proxy, https, squid

I want to limit the bandwidth for youtube, so I want to intercept https connections.
I followed several tutorials and can not. Could someone give me a hand ??

```
# Squid listen Port
http_port 192.168.1.215:3128 ssl-bump generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=4MB key=/etc/squid/example.com.private cert=/etc/squid/example.com.cert
# SSL Bump Config
always_direct allow all
ssl_bump server-first all
sslproxy_cert_error deny all
sslproxy_flags DONT_VERIFY_PEER
sslcrtd_program /usr/lib64/squid/ssl_crtd -s /var/lib/ssl_db -M 4MB sslcrtd_children 8 startup=1 idle=1
```

I import the myCA.pem to the webbrowser and then any web https i go i get "The proxy server is refusing connections". if not https go well.

What can i do?????

This is access.log

```
192.168.1.172 TCP_HIT/200 52543 GET http://www.silencio.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/AHJ8239-540x386.jpg - HIER_NONE/- image/jpeg
192.168.1.172 TCP_HIT/200 49912 GET http://www.silencio.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/strokes-2001-adentro-540x386.jpg - HIER_NONE/- image/jpeg
192.168.1.172 TCP_HIT/200 43804 GET http://www.silencio.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/ArcticMonkeys012-540x386.jpg - HIER_NONE/- image/jpeg
192.168.1.172 TCP_DENIED/200 0 CONNECT www.google-analytics.com:443 - HIER_NONE/- -
192.168.1.172 TCP_MISS/301 807 GET http://www.youtube.com/ - HIER_DIRECT/64.233.186.91 text/html
192.168.1.172 NONE/200 0 CONNECT www.youtube.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/64.233.186.91 -
192.168.1.172 NONE/200 0 CONNECT blocklist.addons.mozilla.org:443 - HIER_DIRECT/52.35.149.230 -
```

Thanks!

(i dont speak english)

Comment: You've done too little to request help here. One line of sslBump configuration isn't enough to get working squid. Examine the cache.log to get answers.

Comment: what did you mean? Squid is working but, when i try config the ssl-bump for https... well happend what i tell. if i go back thats lines all work fine.... i put a little of my config because i just asking about that.

Comment: in cache.log i have this line `2016/08/08 16:09:40 kid1|  NF getsockopt(SO_ORIGINAL_DST) failed on local=192.168.1.215:3128 remote=192.168.1.172:47642 FD 12 flags=33: (92) Protocol not available
`

Comment: i keep probe things and i have this now..... if i change to this `http_port 192.168.1.215:3128 https_port 192.168.1.215:3129 intercept ssl-bump generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=4MB key=/etc/squid/example.com.private cert=/etc/squid/example.com.cert` ..... now the webbrowser tells "Secure Connection Failed"... so i think that something is wrong with my cert... but? what? or maybe another thing? Thanks to all

Comment: Have you recompiled Squid 3.3.8 with SHA2 ssl bump support? See http://docs.diladele.com/administrator_guide_4_4/install/ubuntu14/squid.html, the gadgets.cc.sha256.patch. Without this you will always get "Secure Connection Failed" because of SHA-1 sunsetting...

Answer (score 0):

The first recommendation with intercepting HTTPS is to use the latest squid version available. As of this writing the Squid-3.5.19+ are required for useful SSL-Bump. Using older versions is just asking for trouble.